# Use power series to solve the initial value problem: $(x^2-1)y”+10xy’+8y=0, y(0)=1, y’(0)=0.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\begin{align}
(x^2-1)y”+10xy’+8y&=0 \\ 
y(0)&=1  \\
y’(0)&=0
\end{align}
$$

I have attempted this problem about 10 times with no avail. I know that the part of the solution that is $x^{2n+1}=0$. I have gotten an expression for the left side that is $C_{n+2}=C_n(n+8)/(n+2)$. After writing terms out to $C_{10}$, I obtained $(16*14*12*10*8)/(10*8*6*4*2)$

I can easily identify the denominator as $2^n*n!$. My problem lies with the numerator. I attempted to pull out a 2 & enter the solution as $2*(n+4)!/(2^n*n!)$ or variations of that like with no two in the numerator and $2^n-1$ in the denominator but that is not correct. Any advice?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel to see what's really going on.

Let $a_m=c_{2m}$.  Then $a_{m+1}=\dfrac{2m+8}{2m+2}a_m=\dfrac{m+4}{m+1}a_m$.

Now we compute
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align*}
c_0=a_0&=1\\
c_2=a_1&=\frac41\\
c_4=a_2&=\frac52\times\frac41\\
c_6=a_3&=\frac63\times\frac52\times\frac41\\
c_8=a_4&=\frac7{\cancel4}\times\frac63\times\frac52\times\frac{\cancel4}1\\
c_{10}=a_5&=\frac{8}{\cancel 5}\times\frac7{\cancel 4}\times\frac63\times\frac{\cancel 5}2\times\frac{\cancel 4}1\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
$$
which is more neatly expressed as
$$
c_{2m}=\frac{(m+3)(m+2)(m+1)}{3!}=\binom{m+3}{3}=\binom{-4}{m}(-1)^m.
$$
So $y=(1-x^2)^{-4}$.  The appearence of $(x^2-1)^{-4}$ shouldn't come as a surprise because the original differential equation can be written as
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(x^2-1)^5y'\right]+8(x^2-1)^4y=0.
$$

Comment: +1 got the same answer  $$y=(x^2-1)^{-4}$$

Comment: The answer is supposed to be reported in the form of y=summation from n=0 to infinity(equation*x^2n).

Comment: No, using a particular method doesn't mean you report the final answer in that way.  For example, using Laplace transform doesn't mean you report the final solution as (inverse) Laplace transform.  But if you want, you can write, for example, $y=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{m+3}3x^{2m}$.

Comment: @cookiesandfootball his answer is correct I integrated the equation by another methofd and ended with the same answer...